# Building Android app with React Native gives an error babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my app for development with the dev tools of React-Native I don't have any issue and it works fine.

Although when I generate a build using the `assembleRelease` command, I get the following error on Android:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator')
```

[image]

I tried to figure out the issue with the following thread: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4844

I tried cleaning the cache, restarting the computer, using babel-polyfill, using babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 / babel-preset-stage-0 etc.
But still can't find a solution that works for me.

Does anyone encountered this problem and found a solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: Any update since ?